# How to embed files in yocto recipe

Tags: qt, svg, embedded, png, yocto

I would like to know the way to embed files in a yocto recipe so that I can find them on the embedded side (yocto image deployed on an embedded platform). I'm actually doing it with the SRC_URI += instruction in the .bb file but I do not find any of the files I want once booted on my yocto image. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. Are you trying to deploy files on the filesystem or something else?

Comment: Yes I would like to embed png and svg files into the custom ycto image so that I can use them once booted on it. I have find that FILE_${PN} += "path to my directory" seems to be the best way, do you confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking to implement svn / png files in your image. You can simply install them in your rootfs(in a folder like /home/root/images) with a recipe as follow :

```
SUMMARY = "Simple recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "simple file deployment"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552"
SRC_URI = "file://your.png file://COPYING"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install(){
        install -d ${D}/home/root/images
        install -m WXYZ your.png ${D}/home/root/images
}
FILES_${PN} += "/home/root/images/your.png"
```

Note that `WXYZ` are the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will try it today

Comment: I modified a bit your example to make a loop over files in the same directory and it's working pretty well, thanks. 
`` for f in ${S}/images/*; do \
        install -m 0644 $f ${D}${datadir}/${PN}/images/
 done
``

Comment: I will just add a last comment if I can : The last line of you example can be generalised to FILES_${PN} += "/home/root/images" if more than 1 file needs to be included ? Thanks

Comment: yes you can do like FILES_${PN} += "/home/root/images/" if you are sure that the images folder only contains the files generated by your recipes (i.e if it is a folder specific to your recipe, otherwise you pay attention to its content)