# How to copy structured (archive) files to a file system using a Yocto recipe

Tags: embedded, yocto, tar, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I want to create a recipe that puts files in their corrosponding folders on the rootfs of the target system. Similar to when you install an .ipk or .deb file on your system.

The solution should be scalable. Since I could imagine that in the future I pack many files in this way on the image and do not want to copy each one with 'cp' in a script, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980145/how-to-install-recursively-my-directories-and-files-in-bitbake-recipe?rq=2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210321/how-to-embed-files-in-yocto-recipe) solution.

I currently have the following project structure:

```
├── meta-myTest/
│   └── recipes-myTest/
│       └── images/
│           ├── files/
│           │   ├── etc/
│           │   │   └── mySoft/
│           │   │       └── myConf.conf
│           │   ├── opt/
│           │   │   └── mySoft/
│           │   │       └── mySoft.sh
│           │   └── myFiles.tar.gz   // contains etc/ opt/
│           ├── myRecipe.bb
```

Note that I would prefer to have only a .tar.gz (or similar) in the folder 'files'.
At the end the files should be in the system as follows:

```
/
├── etc/
│   └── mySoft/
│       └── myConf.conf
├── opt/
│   └── mySoft/
│       └── mySoft.sh
```

My question: How can I use my 'myRecipe.bb' file to move the 'prestructured' files from my project to the target image as easily as possible?